# Unix- using awk to print in table format

Tags: unix, awk

I want to create a table that looks something like this, where i display the # at the front of every $2 and the Title header but I do not want to store it in my file:

```
Name          ID             Gender

John Smith    #4567734D      Male
Kyle Toh      #2437882L      Male
Julianne .T   #0324153T      Female
```

I got a result like this instead:

```
Name          ID             Gender
#
Name          ID             Gender
John Smith    #4567734D      Male
Name          ID             Gender
Kyle Toh      #2437882L      Male
Name          ID             Gender
Julianne .T   #0324153T      Female
```

By using this command:

```
awk -F: '   {print "Name:ID:Gender\n"} 
            {print $1":#"$2":"$3}' data.txt |column -s ":" -t
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the sample input as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print the headers only in the first line:

```
awk -F: 'NR==1 {print "Name:ID:Gender\n"} {print $1":#"$2":"$3}'
```

or:

```
awk -F: 'BEGIN {print "Name:ID:Gender\n"} {print $1":#"$2":"$3}'
```

Explanation:

An awk program consists of expressions in the form of:

```
CONDITION { ACTIONS } [ CONDITION { ACTIONS }, ... ]
```

... where CONDITION and ACTION optional. If CONDITION is missing, like:

```
{ ACTIONS }
```

... then ACTIONS would be applied to any line of input. In the case above we have two expressions:

```
# Only executed if NR==1
NR==1 {print "Name:ID:Gender\n"}

# CONDITION is missing. ACTIONS will be applied to any line of input
{print $1":#"$2":"$3}
```

Comment: Or perhaps more typically, in a begin block: `BEGIN{print "Name:ID:Gender\n"}`

Comment: Sure, `BEGIN` can be used as well.

Comment: @hek2mgl Now although the title does not duplicate anymore, how do I avoid printing the # on the second line and keep it blank?

Comment: Just `print $1:"":$3`