# Add echo statement to table for readability

Tags: jquery, shell, unix, google-cloud-platform, sh

I am checking the status of each pipeline and printing the start,end,status timing of each.In future more params could be added.

So as of now I am getting the output as below want it to be in table format so that next time if we add new params that can also be included in tabular format.

```
Pipline : CDF_DT_TELEKOMMOBILE_OF_RO_M4

    The starting time of the pipeline CDF_DT_TELEKOMMOBILE_OF_RO_M4 is : Fri 28 Jan 2022 05:00:03 AM UTC
    The start time of the pipeline CDF_DT_TELEKOMMOBILE_OF_RO_M4 is : Fri 28 Jan 2022 05:04:49 AM UTC
    The end time of the pipeline CDF_DT_TELEKOMMOBILE_OF_RO_M4 is : Fri 28 Jan 2022 05:24:05 AM UTC
    The status of the pipeline CDF_DT_TELEKOMMOBILE_OF_RO_M4 is : COMPLETED
    Pipline : CDF_DT-TelekomMobile-OF-RO_M5
    The starting time of the pipeline CDF_DT-TelekomMobile-OF-RO_M5 is : Fri 28 Jan 2022 03:00:00 AM UTC
    The start time of the pipeline CDF_DT-TelekomMobile-OF-RO_M5 is : Fri 28 Jan 2022 03:04:44 AM UTC
    The end time of the pipeline CDF_DT-TelekomMobile-OF-RO_M5 is : Fri 28 Jan 2022 03:11:29 AM UTC
    The status of the pipeline CDF_DT-TelekomMobile-OF-RO_M5 is : COMPLETED
```

---

```
 export CDF_INSTANCE_ID=uat-data-fusion-instance
 export CDF_REGION=europe-west1
 export AUTH_TOKEN=$(gcloud auth print-access-token)
 export CDAP_ENDPOINT=$(gcloud beta data-fusion instances describe \
     --location=${CDF_REGION} \
     --format="value(apiEndpoint)" \
   ${CDF_INSTANCE_ID})

##I'm pulling the initial run in the list, you might want to sort the runs to make sure it is the latest,
## there may also be filters we can apply to only see runs in the last hour, day, etc. if needed.
last_run_id=`curl -s -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer ${AUTH_TOKEN}" "${CDAP_ENDPOINT}/v3/namespaces/default/apps/${CDF_PIPELINE}/workflows/DataPipelineWorkflow/runs" | jq -r '.[0].runid'`

echo ${last_run_id}

for pipeline in $(cat /home/zcaihar/file1.txt) ; do
##  The times printed here are seconds since epoch, can convert in bash via date --date @, but most languages have an equivalent
pipelineval="$(cut -d'"' -f2 <<<$pipeline)"
echo "Pipline : $pipelineval"
last_run_id=`curl -s -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer ${AUTH_TOKEN}" "${CDAP_ENDPOINT}/v3/namespaces/default/apps/${pipelineval}/workflows/DataPipelineWorkflow/runs" | jq -r '.[0].runid'`
starting_time=`curl -s -X GET -H  "Authorization: Bearer ${AUTH_TOKEN}" "${CDAP_ENDPOINT}/v3/namespaces/default/apps/${pipelineval}/workflows/DataPipelineWorkflow/runs/${last_run_id}" | jq -r '.starting'`
echo "The starting time of the pipeline $pipelineval is : $(date -d @$starting_time)"
start_time=`curl -s -X GET -H  "Authorization: Bearer ${AUTH_TOKEN}" "${CDAP_ENDPOINT}/v3/namespaces/default/apps/${pipelineval}/workflows/DataPipelineWorkflow/runs/${last_run_id}" | jq -r '.start'`
echo "The start time of the pipeline $pipelineval is : $(date -d @$start_time)"
end_time=`curl -s -X GET -H  "Authorization: Bearer ${AUTH_TOKEN}" "${CDAP_ENDPOINT}/v3/namespaces/default/apps/${pipelineval}/workflows/DataPipelineWorkflow/runs/${last_run_id}" | jq -r '.end'`
echo "The end time of the pipeline $pipelineval is : $(date -d @$end_time)"
status=`curl -s -X GET -H  "Authorization: Bearer ${AUTH_TOKEN}" "${CDAP_ENDPOINT}/v3/namespaces/default/apps/${pipelineval}/workflows/DataPipelineWorkflow/runs/${last_run_id}" | jq -r '.status'`
echo "The status of the pipeline $pipelineval is : $status"
done
```

Comment: I have used jq in the curl command that why used the tag and also I want UNIX table kind of structure column/rows value.

Comment: You mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674715/unix-using-awk-to-print-in-table-format